# Script - GmailApp.SendEmail with InlineImages from Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Hy, im trying to make a script to send inline images from an alias gmail account. I found most of the code in GmailApp-s documentation, but now im stuck at the last step... Plese plese help, how do i get this part to work?

Thank you!

```
var html =  
'<body>' + 
  '<img src='cid:image'>' +
'</body>' 

    function testGmailApp() {  
var ImageBlob = DriveApp
                      .getFileById('0Bx4vy5p9TA6bekY3Q2ZNdzViVkE')
                      .getBlob()
                      .setName("ImageBlob");
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
'example@gmail.com', 
'test GmailApp', 
'test',{
htmlBody: html, 
inlineImages: {image: ImageBlob}
      });
```

}

Comment: Welcome. Are getting an error? If so, please include it textually. For further details on guidelines for this kind of questions see [mcve].

Comment: You can follow the example here to insert a [inline image](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)) for mail app. The syntax for mail app and gmail app is same in this case.

Comment: Missing ; before statement. (line 3, file "attach")
. @Jack Brown - that is the first thing i tried, just addedd the g in front of mail, and it didnt work anymore.

Comment: also the 3rd line in the code i pasted above is wrong, it should be:    '<img src='cid:image'/>' +

Comment: You should be able to use the edit link at the end of the question to edit the question. That is a crucial error, that most readers will point to.

Comment: To fix your error do you need to modify the syntax to `'<h2> Test <img src = "cid:image"> </h2><br />'`, please note the use of single and double quotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you insert an inline image to your email. You can find an example of this in the [documentation for MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)). In this particular case of sending an inline image, the syntax for both functions remains the same.

As mentioned in the documentation, the first thing step to insert the inline image is to insert an `img` tag with `src =" cid:"Name of the image blob in inlineimages object here"` 
The html string will look like this:

```
var html =  
'<body>' + 
  '<h2> Test <img src = "cid:image"> </h2><br />' +
'</body>'
```

The remaining function remains the same.
**Note:** src points to cid: image, the name of the key in the inline image object.

Final code:

```
var html =  
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2> Test <img src = "cid:image"> </h2><br />' +
    '</body>'

    function testGmailApp() {  
var ImageBlob = DriveApp
                      .getFileById('0Bx4vy5p9TA6bekY3Q2ZNdzViVkE')
                      .getBlob()
                      .setName("ImageBlob");
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
'someone@gmail.com', 
'test GmailApp', 
'test',{
htmlBody: html, 
inlineImages: {image: ImageBlob}
      }); 
}
```

Comment: if this answers your question, please accept the solution using the clicking the checkmark next to this answer.